# Give me idea to design list form - screenshot

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've been tasked to move information currently being tracked in Excel into SharePoint. Attached is screenshot of excel file they use to collect information. Now I need to move it into SharePoint Online.

Question are predefined. Responses should be able to be extracted into excel or somewhere they can see the question and its related answers/corrective actions/date/comments etc. Those question should come up in a report when they generate one.

I created a SP list with the following columns:

Questions - drop down

Yes/No/NA - Radio

Corrective - Text

Date - Date

Comment- Text

Reporting for this will not be reader friendly as, apart from question, none will have an identifier or unique value.

[image: screenshot of excel sample file]

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new custom list for the questions with your required fields as the following:

- Open your SharePoint site.
- Click on the right gear icon > from the menus > select add a new app or site contents then add a new app.

[image]

- Select custom list.

[image]

- Provide the name of the list.

[image]

- The list should be now created.
- From the above ribbon > select list settings.
- below columns add a new column and select its data type.

[image]

- Now you can add a new item / edit /delete.
- Depend on your requirements, you can create a new list for answers with the same above steps, just make a question column as lookup column to read your questions from the first list. or just use only one list and add a column for answers/corrective actions/date as a multiline column.
- Once you have added your items, you can export the list items to excel from the above ribbon of the list.

[image]

For more details check [Simple Ways to Create Custom List in SharePoint 2013](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1010356/Simple-Ways-to-Create-Custom-List-in-SharePoint)

Comment: Thanks - I edit my question - I know the basics but

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint provides surveys as an [out of the box list customization](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-survey-EA52A787-822E-4F7E-B5ED-77BB14DF3ABA?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) that lets you create your own questions and provides tooling for result summarization. You can add your questions and then add [branching logic](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-branching-logic-to-a-survey-e100ebcf-2155-4cea-b068-647fb5ca785e) based on the answers to get additional information.

For example, if one question was "*Q1: Have you completed work on X?*", you could branch on yes to "*Q1a: What work was completed?*" and have no branch to the next question in the survey (e.g. "*Q2: Have you completed work on Y?*"). Questions are not numbered automatically, so you can add your own numbering system to the question title as the responder goes through the survey.

The survey also allows you to prevent users from taking the survey more than once. The results of the survey can then be [exported for analysis](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-results-of-a-survey-76e32bcc-5638-4f99-9585-d770d348ee16).

Comment: Unfortunately, surveys are limited in how you can display the results. "Show all responses" just shows a list of numbered responses. I don't use surveys because of this, and because the method for responding to a survey is different from all the other types of content (i.e., it doesn't have an "add new item" link).